# why does Eclipse import a class when referencing it with @See

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Why does Eclipse add an import for the target class of a Javadoc @see comment?

If you run this through findbugs or PMD they complain that its an unused import.

So which is correct? Personally I can't see why eclipse wants to import it.

```
 import java.util.List;
 /**
 * @see List
 */
```

The same is true for 'link'

```
 import java.util.List;
 /**
 * {@link List}
 */
```

Does any have any ideas why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The important thing to understand about import statements are that they are simply a convenience mechanism for the developer to avoid having to use the Fully Qualified Name (FQN) for a `Type` everywhere. For example, importing `java.util.List` will let you refer to it by simply using the simple name `List` as opposed to using `java.util.List` everywhere.

Imports have *no* effect on the efficiency or size of the generated bytecode since their use is as explained above and they do not cause any classes to be 'linked' or anything like that with your class.

In the case of the JavaDoc comments, if you use the FQN , Eclipse wouldn't need to import in order to resolve the `Type` reference. As it is, you're using the simple name which is ambiguous so Eclipse imports the appropriate `Type`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Eclipse, but Javadoc needs the import if you don't write the full name in the `{@link}` or `@see` tag. So you could try

```
@see java.util.List
```

instead.

Comment: [SteveR](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6076839/stever) would like to add: If you don't want to see the fully qualified name in the javadoc you can also use `@see java.util.List List` (which also applies in `@link` tags).

Answer (score 1):

The only reason Eclipse does that is, so that while going over your source code, you could do a command click (ctrl + click) and navigate to the class in @see.

Otherwise your class name will not have context. The only other workaround is to give full context path in see also. (along with package name).

Comment: shame the Eclipse doesn't have the option to automatically link to the full package.

Answer (score 0):

An unused import is one that is not needed by the Java compiler.

So PMD is right about flagging it.